# Navigation at footer in CSS is moving when hovered

Tags: html, css, navigation

I tried implementing a `<nav>` at footer, this is the end result [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Xbow23/xv4j102w/) which is completely wrong, the whole nav moves when its hovered tho I haven't kept anything related to moment. I need the items in `<nav>` to be constant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
footer{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.center-footer{
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-nav nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 27px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.footer-nav nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
    padding: 5px;
}

.footer-nav nav ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: it worked can you please explain? it would be really helpful

Comment: your prbolem for your paddings, `.footer-nav nav ul li a` `.footer-nav nav ul li a:hover` `.footer-nav nav ul li` they are should have same padding , like 5

Comment: What both of us other guys said way before you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.footer-nav nav ul li a:hover` padding is doing it:

```
.footer-nav nav ul li a:hover {
   background-color: #111;
    //padding: 5px;
}
```

So either add padding to the `.footer-nav nav ul li`  or remove it (see above) during `:hover`.  If you want padding on all items:

```
.footer-nav nav ul li a {
     padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: No need to down vote me for answering is question.  If I have done something wrong please let me know so i can fix.

Comment: I didnt.. I am just looking at the answer!!

Comment: @GladwinJames wasn't referring to you.  Someone is trolling and downvoted my answer.

Comment: when I removed `padding: 5px;` the hover looks clumsy, I added  `padding: 5px;` so that there would be space between text and hovered colour in all sides

Comment: I am trying to do something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black_right)

Comment: This is the same answer as above.  Padding is your issue.  You have padding only on hover.   There is no need to redefine it as mentioned above .  Use CSS to your advantage and only change background image on hover.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your fiddle you have a colon after the a, which makes it not work properly in the fiddle.

```
    .footer-nav nav ul li a:{
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Second, you need to have the same padding width on the a in its regular state, and when its in :hover, otherwise you will always get a jump.

Third, there is no need to set your "a" to block.

Fourth, set a transition to make things smoother.

```
 .footer-nav nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: all ease-in .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in .3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-in .3s;
  -o-transition: all ease-in .3s;
}

.footer-nav nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  transition: all ease-in .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in .3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-in .3s;
  -o-transition: all ease-in .3s;
}
```

Comment: The transition thing is a bonus, no need to use it if you don't want to.